# My Ethereum balance not showing up in Mist 0.8.6 or Ethereum wallet 0.8.6

Tags: wallets, synchronization, balances, backup

I have just switched to parity because geth doesn't work at all for me. I have synced and opened new mist 0.8.6 but I don't see my balance. What am I doing wrong? How to add an account and show my balance? I have also imported keys from the old app data folder or to be more specific, I have replaced the whole Ethereum folder and Mist folder in the roaming sub directory by the ones used the last time with the 0.8 wallet.

Last wallet I have used was 0.8

Thanks guys

Comment: Many of us are having this same issue, I've been looking everywhere for the answer but simply no luck...

Comment: So what a heck should we do? Just have our money stuck at the moment? I didn't manage to sync even parity. It hot stuck 50k blocks to go and it just skips on the same black. So I can't update by running geth because of the Ddos. Can't update by running parity. Even if I update, can't see my balance since 0.8.6 doesn't show them up.

Comment: Anybody has any option to access my funds. I must say I am disappointed.